# How to install 32 bit glibc on 64 bit ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, x86, 32bit-64bit, glibc

I am trying to learn the C Calling conventions in assembly language. To do so, I made a simple program using the `puts` function from the C standard library.

I assembled and linked the program with the following commands :-

`nasm -f elf file.asm`
`gcc -m32 file.asm -o file`

The nasm produces the right object file but when running the gcc to link the object files, I am getting error.
Looking at the error I have figured it out that I don't have the 32 bit version of glibc on my system. How can I install it.     I already have installed [this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libc6-i386) package installed.

I have 64 bit ubuntu 12.04 as my OS.

EDIT :- I have installed the following packages, but the problem is still not solved :-

1)ia32-libs
2) libc6-i386

Comment: If you need help resolving any error, it always makes sense to post the _exact text of the error message_.

Answer (score 24):

This command will install the 32bit glibc libraries on 64 bit Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib
```

This is the proper syntax for linking assembly object code into an executable using gcc:

```
gcc -m32 objectfile.o -o executablefile
```

(nasm -felf32 already creates `objectfile.o`; the `.asm` file should not appear on GCC's command line.  GCC can assemble+link a `.S` file in one step using GAS syntax, but NASM is a separate package.)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Then there must be an explanation as to why. Posting code only does *not* teach anything

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've elaborated a bit on my answer. I simply wanted to share the command I used to get the 32bit glibc libraries.

Comment: This helped me cross-compile for ARM on a x64 with debien, with arm-none-eabi-gcc from 2015q2.

Answer (score 2):

> I  assembled and linked the program with the following commands :- 
>   `nasm -f elf file.asm` 
>   `gcc -m32 file.asm -o file`

This is wrong. Your first `nasm` command is probably creating a `file.o` file (and you should check that, e.g. with `ls -l file.o`). The second `gcc`  command does not do what you wish.

But `gcc` does not know about `*.asm` file extensions (it knows about `.S` for preprocessable GNU assembler syntax, and `.s` for assembler code, but probably handle unknown extensions like `.asm` as ELF object files by default, however `file.asm` is *not* an ELF object file). You should try linking with

```
gcc -Wall -v -m32 file.o -o file
```

Notice that you give to [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) an [*object* file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) in [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) (for the [*linker*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) invoked by `gcc`) which you previously produced with `nasm`.

<sup>(you might later remove the `-v` option to `gcc`)</sup>

Alternatively, use the GNU `as` assembler syntax (not the *nasm* one), name your file `file.S` (if you want it to be preprocessed) or `file.s` (without preprocessing) and use `gcc -v -Wall -m32 file.s -o myprog` to compile it.

BTW, to understand more about [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention), read the [x86-64 ABI spec](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi.pdf) (and the similar one for 32 bits x86 ...), make a small C example file `some-example.c`, then run `gcc -S -fverbose-asm -O some-example.c` and look into the produced `some-example.s` with an editor or pager.

Learn also more about [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) then use [readelf](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.25/binutils/readelf.html) (& `objdump`) appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You want to install a package called 'ia32-libs'